# Calling Microsoft Exchange Web Service from .net application works in development but not on server

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices

On my development machine I downloaded and installed the Microsoft Exchange Web Services api. I have added a reference to the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices dll in a .net web application.
I have created a page that will allow users to set a calendar appointment in other users' Outlook calendars. I have this code:

```
ExchangeService myService =new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
myService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myName", "myPassword");
myService.AutodiscoverUrl("myEmailAddress@myCompany.com");

Appointment a = new Appointment(myService);
a.Subject = "Test Appointment";
a.Start = new DateTime(2012,5,15,14,45,0,DateTimeKind.Local);
a.End = new DateTime(2012,5,15,15,45,0,DateTimeKind.Local);
a.RequiredAttendees.Add(new Attendee("myEmailAddress@myCompany.com");
a.Save(SendInvitationMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

If I run this on my development machine, it works fine and creates the appointment.

If I publish the web application to a local server and try to run it I receive this:

> The Client Access Server version does not match the accessed
>   resource's Mailbox Server version. Use AutoDiscover with the address
>   of the resource being accessed to determine the correct URL to use to
>   access the specified resource.

I have no idea what this means.

If I go on to the server, open IIS and browse to the site, it works perfectly.

So, it runs on my development box okay - creates the appointment in my Outlook calendar okay.
It runs if I go on the server, open IIS and run it - it creates the appointment okay.
If I run it in a browser using http://mylocalServer/myTestApp/OutlookReminder.aspx - it falls over with the error message above.

Comment: Google reveals [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/7cc93263-0d27-4cbd-8513-7f9b4ac6b5db). Does this help?

Comment: Just to check: Are you using *exactly* the same code, including the same e-mail addresses, credentials etc. in both cases?

Comment: Exactly the same code - everything is the same. I run it on my development box - it works fine. I publish the site to a local server - browse it on the server from within IIS - it works fine.

Browse using http://myTestServer/MyTestApp/OutlookReminder.aspx - it does not work.

To Uwe Keim - thanks for your help and the link - I don't understand why it would work from my development box and by browsing from within IIS on the server hosting the site - but does not work when accessing the site in the usual way. If EWS had been disabled - presumably it would not work at all?